# Counting how many times a condition is met in Python

Tags: python

In python, I sometimes write a while statement like

```py
i = 0
while <condition that involves i>:
    i += 1
```

The goal is, of course, to check the number of time the condition is true.
I was wondering if there's a more simple, pythonic way to do it ? something like `i = while <condition that involves i>`, maybe with the walrus operator ?

Here's a more concrete example:

```py
def get_word_num_with_character_index(string: str, index: int) -> int:
    """
    returns the number of the word containing a character, specified by an index

    :param string: the string to analyze
    :param index: the index of the character
    :return: the number of the word containing the specified character
    """

    split_string = string.split(" ")

    i = 0
    while len(" ".join(split_string[:i])) <= index:
        i += 1

    return i - 1


print(get_word_num_with_character_index("jean de la fontaine", 8))
# prints 2, the index of the word containing the 8th character
```

How to simplify it ?

Comment: You *can* use the walrus operator here, but I don't think you should: `i = -1`, `while len(" ".join(split_string[:(i := i + 1)])) <= index: pass`. It's neither simpler nor clearer, it just moves even more logic into the condition without saving a line.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're not looking into using enumerate (returns a counter as part of a `for` loop) or using slicing, such as `"jean de la fontaine"[8]` - correct?

Comment: thanks @riskypenguin, but as you pointed out, it only makes the code more complex, so it's not really what I'm looking for. I was just mentioning the walrus operator as a possible idea

Comment: @C.Harley no, this is just an exemple but i'm trying to get the value of `i` in only one line, using the given condition, in order to get the number of the word in the string where the specified letter is (here, ̀"jean de la fontaine"[8]`). Sorry, I know it's not very clear but I don't see how I can explain the function more clearly than in its docstring

Comment: `sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(lambda i: PREDICATE, itertools.count()))`

Comment: What about `return string[:index+1].count(" ")` ?

Comment: thanks @SylvainD , but this is an example, and I'm looking for a global solution

Comment: To be honest, I have the feeling that it works pretty well. I'd be interested in cases that are not handled properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* replace your

```
    i = 0
    while len(" ".join(split_string[:i])) <= index:
        i += 1
```

with the oneliner using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)

```
    i = next(i for i in count() if len(" ".join(split_string[:i])) > index)
```

or more readably spread over two physical lines (still just one [logical line](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#logical-lines):

```
    i = next(i for i in count()
             if len(" ".join(split_string[:i])) > index)
```

Both have advantages. The `while` solution has less clutter, the `next` solution makes it clearer that the whole point of the snippet is to compute `i`.

If you already have a function for the condition, a good alternative would be [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
    def condition(i):
        return len(" ".join(split_string[:i])) <= index

    i = next(dropwhile(condition, count()))
```

As a oneliner, just to see how long/ugly it is in this case:

```
    i = next(dropwhile(lambda i: len(" ".join(split_string[:i])) <= index, count()))
```

So I'd likely really only use it if I had it as a function already.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `itertools.count()` is what I needed right now, but I keep  `dropwhile()` in mind, it is also very relevant.
I'm always open to other ideas.
But the word "could" in your message suggests that this is not a good idea. It's true that it's not very clear. So you recommend not to use it, but to leave the "while" as it is?

Comment: I meant that as there's nothing wrong with the while loop. In this particular case, I'm undecided which I prefer, while or next. So you *could* switch, but you really don't have to.

Comment: Ok, I will keep this in mind, thank you !

Comment: Put differently: Many Python beginners will write or see `while` loops and see experienced coders point out that they're horrible and that it should be done differently, and misunderstand that as "while loops are *always* horrible" rather than the meant "this particular while loop is horrible". Similar to the misconception "to be pythonic, I must write this code as a oneliner" :-)